# There was no endpoint listening at ServiceStack/SyncReply.svc

Tags: servicestack

I downloaded the ServiceStack Hello demo and tried to consume it in VS2010, but when I call the service all I get is:

There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/ServiceStack/SyncReply.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: Here is my end points:<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/ServiceStack/SyncReply.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply"
        contract="ServiceStack.ISyncReply" name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/ServiceStack/AsyncOneWay.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay"
        contract="ServiceStack.IOneWay" name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" />
    </client>